# Debian Audio Issue

Tags: debian, audio

So, the problem here is that my audio worked before this.

Last night, I left my computer on. When I woke up, I tried to wake it from sleep, but it seemed it had crashed for some reason. I restarted my computer, and it worked fine, except the audio is gone.

I really have no idea what is going on, except that Debian is completely ignoring my motherboard audio card all of a sudden. I tested audio recording in Audacity, and I was getting a record signal, but it was just noise from the look of it, and had no correlation to my actual microphone.

My settings say I am using alsa with PULSE, which is normal.

The only information I can give is that I did attempt to get some OSS compatibility packages, but that was a couple days ago, and I have surly restarted my computer since then.

If you need any system information, let me know in the comments and I will post it.

EDIT:

In the audio manager, all of my audio devices have been replaced wit "Dummy Output," and the normal devices are not selectable, but listed. My normal device, called "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" is one of these devices I can't select, meaning that my audio will not work until I can get that device working. Maybe I edited the modules when working with the OSS stuff, causing the devices to not be selectable?

EDIT:

/proc/asound does not exist, which is an issue...

Comment: Could we get the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`?

Comment: @derobert sure thing! One sec...

Comment: @derobert It appears that /proc/asound doesnt exist, thats alarming...

Comment: Which OSS stuff were you installing? /var/log should have a few log files if you don't remember (apt and dpkg both log package installs, so does aptitude). Seems like you've got no ALSA drivers loaded. Could also look in /etc/modprobe.d to see if there is a file blacklisting alsa (alsa drivers are all named `snd_*`, and the main one is `snd`)

Comment: @derobert Yeah, I remember blacklisting something, I will look at modprobe. Also, I uninstalled oss-compat to see if that helped. I tried looking at my history, but they are all zipped up as gz files, and I am too lazy to pipe a decompression to cat.

Comment: BTW, random aside, I'd like to introduce you to `etckeeper`. Easily puts `/etc` under version control, so you can quickly see what you changed—even if it was at the end of a late night of trying to get this #(@!# thing to work.

Comment: @derobert okay, so in oss4-base_noALSA.conf (damn, must have installed something to get that on here), there are a million `snd*` drivers being blacklisted. That makes me thing that there was some other package I got, I will look through my history.

Comment: @derobert okay, found some more packages involving oss, and uninstall purged all of them. Restarting now...

Comment: that worked, submitting as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall (purge) any `oss` replacement packages, like `oss4-base`.